# prevent jquery function run on all classes with same name

Tags: jquery

Im trying to run an alert box, but only on the element Im clicking. since I have a couple of elements with the same name.

It worked on a JSfiddle I created but not when Im running it on the site. then the alert box popping up as many elements i have with the same name.

Any ideas ?

```
$('insta').click(function(){alert("alert",this) })
```

Comment: The code you have shown is looking for a literal `<insta>` element.

Comment: `.insta` - class , `#insta` - ID , `insta` - element . [JQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Will edit my question then :)

Comment: `alert()` accepts a single argument, vis `alert(message)`. The second argument will at best be ignored,  or at worst will give uncertain behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.insta').click(function(){alert("alert",this) })
```

.insta means a CLASS #insta means DIV.